# API Gateway is failing preflight when we access over organisation internal VPN

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, vpn

I'm stuck in a problem.

I have configured an API Gateway which in turn talks to a lambda in the same region.

But requests are failing with "Failed to load response" during preflight only when we connect to internal VPN of the organisation, else that is working fine.

API Gateway is "Edge optimised" and thats not private.

Any insights on how to troubleshoot or how to fix this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know if this is still an ongoing problem but can you share vpn and api gateway deployment details if possible ? And try to check the dns resolvers and api gateway integration method for expected request model info and etc. That worked in the past for me. Also, do not forget to trying to mimic the request from the VPN host.

Comment: Actually, we resolved it by creating the custom domain for those end points, Its working fine for now, but still unsure about why it was not working when we are hitting API Gateway URL